# a c program which calculating and printing the gcd and lcm of n numbers

Tags: c

My program should calculate and print the gcd and lcm of n numbers. First user will enter the number n. Then, user will enter the n many numbers and these numbers should assign an array. Lastly, gcd and lcm will be calculeted and printed.

**I can not use the user-defined functions in my program.** I know this is strange but it is a must.

I wrote my code. It calculates and prints the gcd correctly. But when it comes to lcm it prints meaningless numbers. Also the program don't start without enter 2 numbers. Can somebody tell me where my mistake is?

here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define max 100
int main()
{

    int n,i,ii, product,gcd,lcm,arr[max],j=1;

    printf(" How many numbers do you want to enter?\n");
    scanf("%d ",&n);


    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {

        printf(" enter the %d. number: \n",(i+1));
        scanf("%d ",&arr[i]);

    }

    gcd = arr[0];


    while(j<n)
        {

        if(arr[j]%gcd==0){
                j++;

                         }

        else{

            gcd=arr[j]%gcd;
            }

       }
       
       
        printf("GCD of all numbers is %d \n", gcd);
        
        
        
        product=1;
        
        for(ii=0;ii<n;ii++){
            
            product=product*arr[i];
        }
        
        lcm=product/gcd;
        
        printf("LCM of all numbers is %d",lcm);
        
        

    return 0;
}
```

[image: and here is an output of my program:]

Comment: You might be getting integer overflow. Use a 64-bit type and cast during the multiplication. If that still overflows, you'll need to work with prime factors and their powers, cancelling the powers.

Comment: Which numbers shoud i convert into 64 bit type and how can i do that? I am a beginner at programming

Comment: A 64-bit `product`. But since the snapshot post, I don't see how 3 x 6 x 9 can overflow `int`.

Comment: Typo: change `product=product*arr[i];` to `product=product*arr[ii];`

Comment: I rolled back the question to be the one that contains the code fault which was answered. Please don't follow fault finding with live updates and corrections.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Also the program don't start without enter 2 numbers

**Reason:**

```
scanf("%d ",&n);
```

Here, there is extra space inside `scanf`. A space character in a `scanf` format causes it to explicitly read and ignore as many space characters as it can. So with `scanf("%d ",&n);` after reading a number, it will continue to read characters, discarding all whitespace until it sees a non-whitespace character on the input.

Remove the space in `scanf` statement. Use `scanf("%d",&n);`

Comment: Good spot, I only noticed when I tried the code. But the code is still faulty, have not yet seen why.

Comment: Yeahh didn't realize that and  did that 2 times. Now i fixed it, thanks. Now my only problem is nonsensical numbers